# How to check image is loaded completely or not using JavaScript in Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I m trying to execute some code when image is not loaded. I m using following code:

```
<script language="javascript">

object = new Image();
object.src = '$imageurl';

if(!object.complete)
{
    //do something
}

</script>
```

But this is not working in Facebook. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a function using [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) while the image is loading and stop it as soon as it has loaded.

```
function () {
var img = new Image();

var intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
  /* stuff to do with "img" while it is loading */
}, 250);

img.onload = function () { window.clearInterval(intervalId); }
img.src = 'http://example.com/image.jpg';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onload` event which fires when image has been loaded like this:

```
object.onload = function(){
  // image has been loaded
};
```

Also have a look at:

- [Getting an Image's onload to Fire](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/image-onload-isnt-being-called)

**Update:**

To run code unless image has not been loaded, you could do this way:

```
<script language="javascript">

object = new Image();

// here image is not loaded yet

object.onload = function(){
  // image has been loaded
};

// image loaded, show it
object.src = '$imageurl';

</script>
```

I suspect you are using php by seeing `$imageurl`, you need to replace the line:

```
object.src = '$imageurl';
```

With:

```
object.src = '<?php echo $imageurl;?>';
```

Comment: Re `object.src = '$imageurl';`: it is possible that (s)he is using a <a href="http://php.net/heredoc">heredoc</a>, thus negating the need for `<?php echo`, but judging by the user name, I'd say that was unlikely.

Comment: @janmoesen: I can't judge from the username :) but I pointed out just in case :) And even with heredoc it should be like `{$imageurl}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onLoad event

```
<script language="javascript">

object = new Image();
object.src = '$imageurl';

object.onLoad = imageHasLoaded();

</script>
```